# How does istream::operator>>( const char& ) as no such function is implemented?

Tags: c++, operators, istream

Looking at [`istream` documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator%3E%3E), you will see that there is no implementation of function `istream &operator>>( char& )`, but if you compile and run the code below, it will work just as expected.

```
#include<iostream>

int main( ) {

  char c;

  std::cin >> c;

  std::cout << c << std::endl;

  return( 0 );

}
```

Given `cin` is an object for class istream, which specialization of `operator>>` is called
when `std::cin >> c;` is executed?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator-free/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`operator>>` also is implemented as [non-member functions](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator-free/).

> istream& operator>> (istream& is, char& c)

Comment: See also § 27.7.2.2.3/11.

Answer (score 1):

As stated [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream), [`operator>>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt2) is also implemented as *non-member-function* of cin.

Non-member function :

```
istream& operator>>( istream& st, char& ch );
```

There is always the standard stated it explicitly in the section *§ 27.7.2.2.3* :

> **27.7.2.2.3 basic_istream::operator>> [istream::extractors]**
>
> 11/ *Returns:* in.
>
> ```
>     template<class charT, class traits> basic_istream<charT,traits>& operator>>
>         (basic_istream<charT,traits>& in, charT& c);
>
>     template<class traits> basic_istream<char,traits>& operator>>
>         (basic_istream<char,traits>& in, unsigned char& c);
>
>     template<class traits> basic_istream<char,traits>& operator>>
>         (basic_istream<char,traits>& in, signed char& c);
> ```